# Git submodule vs Git clone

Tags: git, github

I am working on an open source project on GitHub.

It has a subdirectory /Vendor in which it has a **copy** of several external libraries. Original maintainer of the project  updated this directory with newer copy of external library once in a while.

One developer send me a pull request with idea to replace this **copy** by **git submodule**.

And I am considering whether it's good idea or not.

Git submodule Pros:

- Submodules were specifically designed for similar scenarios
- It removes possibility of accidental commit to Vendor which will be overwritten while next update

Git submodule Cons:

- It looks like git submodules pushes complexity from maintainer to a person who will clone/pull the project (additional steps required after you clone to start working with the project: "git submodule init", "git submodule update"

What's your opinion on this?

One more thing. This problem is reasonably small size library with very limited external dependencies. I think any build tool would be overkill for it for now.

Comment: Alternatively they can do `git clone --recursive` and then don't have to do the submodule commands. No one else had mentioned this tidbit; most people I know that have submodules advertise this in the README.

Answer (score 10):

An alternative to a submodule is to use [`git subtree`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt). This gives the benefits of `git submodule` but without pushing the complexity to the end user. The third party repository is merged into the main project tree, but there is metadata stored in such a way that you can:

- extract the third party repository later, if any interesting changes have been made
- merge in new updates from the third party repository (note *merge*, not overwrite)

For Git users who are not sophisticated enough to understand submodules, the subtree approach makes getting a clone of your project no more difficult than any other clone. A short blurb from the documentation:

> Subtrees allow subprojects to be included within a subdirectory
>   of the main project, optionally including the subproject's
>   entire history.
>
> For example, you could include the source code for a library
>   as a subdirectory of your application.
>
> Subtrees are not to be confused with submodules, which are meant for
>   the same task. Unlike submodules, subtrees do not need any special
>   constructions (like .gitmodule files or gitlinks) be present in
>   your repository, and do not force end-users of your
>   repository to do anything special or to understand how subtrees
>   work. A subtree is just a subdirectory that can be
>   committed to, branched, and merged along with your project in
>   any way you want.

I had set up a project at work using submodules, and the troubles with keeping submodules up to date in everybody's clones was too much work. I recently changed to using subtrees everywhere and those problems disappeared.

Note that git-subtree is part of the [`git/contrib`](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib) directory, and must be installed separately.

Answer (score 5):

Using submodules prevents you from making local changes to the code & creates a dependency on the external repository.  If you're sure you will *never* want to customize a library or make local bug fixes and can be sure that the external server will *always* be available when you want to clone a new copy they're the way to go.

In short - do you want to simply use the libs or do you consider them part of your codebase?  If they're not 'your' code, why are they in version control and not just something you require to have installed?

Comment: Submodules do not prevent you from making local changes. On the contrary, they allow you to track those changes and use different versions (your tweaks or library releases) of the library in different projects.

Answer (score 5):

One drawback of using submodules is that the tarballs or zip-archives on Github (and many other services) do not include the sources of submodules. That is, the archives are not self-contained. This is of an issue if the repository is small and does not really have a build script, like a static HTML site depending on a JavaScript library.

Answer (score 3):

This is an ideal place to use submodules. They reduce the size and complexity of your repository and make it easier to update the external libraries to a new version.

They're not hard to figure out how to use, and they are fairly commonly used in this situation, so just make a note in the project's README that you make use of submodules and what to do, and people ought to be able to figure it out. The first time I encountered a repository with a submodule I got it up and running in 10 to 15 minutes and have never had an issue with figuring out what to do since.

Comment: As an addendum to this, if your application fails to initialize you might want to put a check into place to verify that the submodule has been initialized - and provide a friendly error message if it hasn't.

Comment: Also see Lekensteyn's answer about zip-archives lacking submodule files. This means submodules are perhaps not the best approach if you are supplying code publicly, but are fine for private code that is guaranteed to be cloned. Otherwise, prefer subtrees.